# How to stash form data in order to show confirmation page before submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, file, post, upload

I have a multipart form that is very long and includes file input fields. My client would like for the user to be able to review the data they have entered before sending the data along to the remote server. The currently working implementation simply takes the form data and submits it to the external web service. Since there is already a large amount of validation and SOAP request boilerplate written, I'm simply dropping in a controller action between them. So, all I need to do is take the form data supplied to the "Review" action and send it along to the "Submit" action.

### Here is the flow of the controllers and views involved so far:

- The form is rendered, user enters data, hits "continue"
- Form is validated, then form data is sent to "review" page
- Action for view page creates `params[:clean]` and populates it with human-readable form data
- View displays table with option | data, with a "Submit" button at the bottom

### What I've tried so far:

- `session[:form_data] = params` this causes the "cannot dump File" error

### Considered but would rather avoid if possible:

- Creating another form on "Review" view that is populated from params and POSTs to the submit url

Of note is that the uploaded files are not being handled by the application. The client's SOAP architecture handles everything - I just need to have a page that holds onto form data, then passes it along in the event that the customer is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

## Here is what I ended up doing

### In the "review" action:

```
session[:uploaded_files_array] = Array.new
session[:application_data] = params.except(*exclusions, *files)

if params[:uploaded_file]
  params[:application_data][:uploaded_file] = true
  file_name = session[:current_customer] + "more_stuff"
  uploaded_path = File.join(Dir.tmpdir, file_name)
  File.open(uploaded_path, "wb") do |f|
    f.write(params[:uploaded_file].read)
  end
  session[:uploaded_files_array] << uploaded_path
end
```

### In the "submit" action:

```
uploaded_files_array = session[:uploaded_files_array]  
params = session[:application_data]  
unless uploaded_files_array.blank?  
    Resque.enqueue(ConfirmationDocumentUploader, uploaded_files_array, session[:current_customer] ["DocumentID"] )
end
```

So basically, I wrote the uploaded files to temporary locations in the filesystem, and stored their locations within the session. I also copied all relevant parameters from params into the session. Then, during the submit process, I simply read overwrite params from the session, and enqueue a worker for the files using the array of paths.

Hopefully this will be useful to someone else, I imagine that having a review page, so that customers can confirm their choices, is a fairly common desire.